# Set 'Reduce transparency' by app?

Tags: macos, mojave

Can I keep transparency for menu bar, and 'Reduce transparency' for some apps?

Comment: Can I ask why? Is there some particular effect you're trying to achieve? My answer would be "No", as that's not the way the Window Manager works, and Apple is unlikely to spent time creating such a feature. But I have no definite evidence that this cannot be ruled out.

Comment: @benwiggy First I want reduced transparency (at least for apps). In light mode, menu bar is too bright. Using dark mode or dark-menubar-only mode could be a solution, but it has problems too.

Comment: And you don't like the global "Reduce Transparency" setting in System Preferences > Accessibility > Display...?